# How TypeScript can defines Build-In Types to JavaScript on its compilation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I started studying on scripting languages especially JavaScript. It was fine and I started confused when I study Angular2 with TypeScript.

I realized that TypeScript can define Build-In Types such as string, number and Objects, and TypeScript will produce JavaScript on its compilation.

Here started my confusion, how TypeScript defines Generic Types on JavaScript since JavaScript is Prototype based Language and it can't define Types.

Example, how it is possible to compile the following codes into JavaScript.

```
interface Person {
   name : string,
   age : number
}
```

Can anyone explain this? Scripting is fun, but sometimes it is difficult to understand.  (^^

Comment: It does not, simple as that.

Comment: You are misusing the word "generic type", which has a specific meaning in TypeScript, involving parameterizing a type with another class, such as `Promise<boolean>`. `string` etc. are not called "generic types", they are called "built-in types". To answer your specific question, the `interface` is not compiled into JS at all. It is only used by TS when compiling and checking.

Comment: Thank you @torazaburo, now, I understood what is generic type and how I misused. +1 for your clear explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. It defines rules(generics, types and so on) only in Typescript level. It only defines `generics` in `TypeScript` level. So when you will see the Javascript-ed code, you can't see anything that is generic.

The same is with `const`. When you create a variable with `const`, you can't change it in `TypeScript` level. But you can change it in JavaScript, because

`const myVar`will be parsed into `var myVar`, if it is not `ES6`

You can see here **[TypeScript to JavaScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20a%20%3D%204%3B%0D%0Avar%20b%3A%20number%20%3D%205%3B%0D%0A)**, to which your codes is translating.